# Labeling dynamic contours whose size changes frame to frame

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Is there a way of recognize and label contours whose size changes frame to frame with openCV
Some of the contour can also vanish after few frames.  Some contours can appear after few
frames etc.,

Any idea?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question, need to add more details, may be some images etc.

Comment: I have hundreds images in which contour like objects appear after certain number of frames. These contours also vanish after certain time. What I want is to label these contours and initially labelled contours should be tracked till they vanish.